# libx264: which parameters can be changed on fly?

Tags: c++, x264, libx264

I know that it is possible to change some encoder parameters on fly, using x264_encoder_reconfig(). From [this](http://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=commit;h=f555cf3758f46f3c4f7a2f05094b16f8f3c25a27) commit I can deduce that we can change ratecontrol parameters - but I was unable to find a clear list of parameters that may be changed.

Question: which parameters of x264 encoder can be changed on fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for the list of reconfigurable options in the source code of libx264 [x264_encoder_try_reconfig function](http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=encoder/encoder.c;hb=HEAD#l1747)