# libx264 : change qp on fly

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I need dynamically change qp value during encoding for certain frames, but 264_encoder_try_reconfig function don't have that option.
If I need change qp on fly,  what should I do?

Thanks,
Jen

Comment: Have you done any research to try to solve this? If so, add what you tried here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981704/libx264-which-parameters-can-be-changed-on-fly may be helpful